# Is it possible to create a variable in google tag manager that refers to form name?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtmetrix

I am trying to create a trigger for a particular form. What is the correct way to refer to form if i have no id?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should be able to create a DOM type variable, change the selection method from the default "id" to "CSS selector" and use that to address the form in question:

[image]

The actual selector might need a bit tweaking (and obviously you'd want to substitute the real name of the form in the square brackets), but basically that is the way to go.

You then create a form submit trigger, set it to "fire on some forms" and use the variable created above to filter the trigger for that specific form.